# How to change checking processes - bitcore-node

Tags: bitcore

We are trying to set up bitcore-node to work with other cryptocurrency core. Lets say that everything in core is pretty much the same like in bitcoin core so everything should work.

After resolving some problems we stuck on starting and exiting node process. It looks like this:

`[2017-11-09T12:20:29.239Z] info: Using config: /Users/gitsad/GIT/bitcore-node/ourcoinNode/bitcore-node.json
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.241Z] info: Using network: testnet
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.242Z] info: Starting bitcoind
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.244Z] info: Using bitcoin config file: /Users/gitsad/GIT/bitcore-node/ourcoinNode/data/dash.conf
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.249Z] info: Starting dash process
OurCoin Core server starting
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.294Z] warn: Dash process unexpectedly exited with code: 0
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.295Z] warn: Restarting dash child process in 5000ms
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.315Z] info: Dash Height: 0 Percentage: 0.01
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.324Z] info: Dash Daemon Ready
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.325Z] info: Starting web
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.369Z] info: Bitcore Node ready
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.802Z] warn: ZMQ connection delay: tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
[2017-11-09T12:20:29.802Z] info: ZMQ connected to: tcp://127.0.0.1:28332`

Process exits and starts again:

`[2017-11-09T12:20:34.301Z] info: Using bitcoin config file: /Users/gitsad/GIT/bitcore-node/ourcoinNode/data/dash.conf
.
.
.
the same stuff`

#### We found in lib code in `bitcore-node/lib/services/bitcoind.js`

`self.spawn.process.once('exit', function(code) {
      if (!self.node.stopping) {
        log.warn('Bitcoin process unexpectedly exited with code:', code);
        log.warn('Restarting bitcoin child process in ' + self.spawnRestartTime + 'ms');
        setTimeout(function() {
          self._spawnChildProcess(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              return self.emit('error', err);
            }
            log.warn('Bitcoin process restarted');
          });
        }, self.spawnRestartTime);
      }
    });`

We changed it by adding `return;` at the end of line:

`self.spawn.process.once('exit', function(code) { return;`

And this resolved our problem with the restarting process.

#### The question is:

Where can we find the conditions on which this function checks the process and how we can change it?

Every help will be appreciated. Thanks!